# Google Run Deployment failed with an image in dockerhub. <Revision Name> is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Resource readiness deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy a service to Google Cloud Runusin using commandline. But it is failing with error below.

```
X Deploying... Revision 'XXXXXXXXX' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again later. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.                                                                         
X Creating Revision... The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again later. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.                                                                                                                                
  . Routing traffic...                                                                                                                     
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...                                                                                                                  
Deployment failed                                                                                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) The service has encountered an error during container import. Please try again later. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiwJo.png)

Below is the command I have used.

```
gcloud run deploy my-service --quiet --platform managed --allow-unauthenticated --region asia-southeast1 --image docker.io/<username>/<imgname> --project <projectid> --memory 1548M --concurrency 1 --platform managed
```

My SDK version

```
Google Cloud SDK 420.0.0
beta 2023.02.24
bq 2.0.86
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.16
core 2023.02.24
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.20
```

My dockerfile is as below.

```
FROM python:3.9-bullseye

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL "3"

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 libgl1 python3-opencv libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Also built image is working fine on local docker engine. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9BM4.png)

My docker hub image size and details are as below

```
COMPRESSED SIZE - 3.54 GB
OS/ARCH - linux/amd64
```

Comment: did you check the logs? You sometime have more detaill on the errors!

Comment: Is the image public?

Comment: No errors on logs and also the image is public.

Comment: This docs page describes the kind of error you have: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#service-agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved!**

Awesome news, I managed to fix my issue! The problem was that my Docker image was **too big**, about **5GB** in size. So, I decided to **optimize my Dockerfile** and remove any unnecessary files, dependencies, and layers to shrink the **size down to 1.9GB.** After doing so, I was able to deploy my application without any errors.

It's important to keep in mind that large Docker images can cause problems during cloud run deployment, so it's always a good idea to optimize them.